# How does flex's order decide how things should be ordered, if elements have the same order integer?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Situation is as follows:

```
<section class="filters">
  <ul>
    <li>Color:
      <ul>
        <li style="order: 4;">Red (4)</li>
        <li style="order: 4;">Blue (4)</li>
        <li style="order: 0;">White (0)</li>
        <li style="order: 2;">Gold (2)</li>
        <li style="order: 1;">Purple (1)</li>
        <li style="order: 2;">Pink (2) </li>
        <li style="order: 2;">Silver (2)</li>
        <li style="order: 0;">Black (0)</li>
        <li style="order: 0;">Brown (0)</li>
        <li style="order: 1;">Yellow (1)</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
.filters ul li ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```

The result:

- Color:

  - Blue (4)
  - Red (4)
  - Silver (2)
  - Pink (2)
  - Gold (2)
  - Yellow (1)
  - Purple (1)
  - Brown (0)
  - Black (0)
  - White (0)

How does it decide blue should be before red? Silver, green and black I can live with: alphabetical. But why does it order blue before red, even though both have an order of 4?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wf4fu13v/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Items with the same `order` appear in document order (though you also specify a reversed direction).

From [the relevant spec](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-flexbox/#order_modified-document-order):

> A flex container lays out its content in order-modified document order#, starting from the lowest numbered ordinal group and going up. Items with the same ordinal group are laid out in the order they appear in the source document.

Combine this with the fact that you specify `column-reverse`, I'd say that "Blue" comes before "Red" because that's the "*reverse* order" in which they appear in your document.

The same holds for "Silver > Pink > Gold", which all have `order` of `2`, and thus appear in reversed order in which they are in the document.

Finally, the same holds for items with `order` of `0`.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. I cannot believe I didn't think of checking the spec. Thank you!